# How to set up Android library to work with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write some Android library to reuse in multiple projects. So I want to be able to house the library in a repo and then import it using gradle. An example of what I want to achieve is Picasso lib.
https://github.com/square/picasso
The only thing I need to do to start using this lib is adding this line to my app build.gradle: `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`
Could someone point me to a reference or provide steps to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this https://medium.com/@anujguptawork/how-to-create-your-own-android-library-and-publish-it-750e0f7481bf

Comment: @StavroXhardha that is not what the OP is asking, or at the very least, if you think that all the OP needs to do is "import it in any project", then provide an answer with the solution, so the OP can follow your expert advice. Otherwise, why bother adding such a non-helpful comment. If the OP knew he/she has to "import" the library, then we wouldn't be reading this question, would be?

Comment: I got it wrong, I will give my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this step by step to upload an android library.
[Click here](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/6-easy-steps-to-upload-your-android-library-to-bintray-jcenter-59e6030c8890) to check in details.
Then you can add in your build.gradle file to use it.

Follow this.

Step 1: Create an account in Bintray with your GitHub/Google account
Step 2: First create a repository in your GitHub. Then add that repository in Bintray.
Step 3: Open your library project in Android Studio and add this line in your build.gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:{latest_version}'

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha07'

        // Step I: add this line
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Step 4: Add project details to the build.gradle file under the /app directory

```
apply plugin: ‘com.android.library’
publish {

    def groupProjectID = '{package_name}'
    def artifactProjectID = '{name_of_your_library}'
    def publishVersionID = 'library_version_code'

    userOrg = '{username_of_bintray}'
    repoName = 'repository_name'
    groupId = groupProjectID
    artifactId = artifactProjectID
    publishVersion = publishVersionID
    desc = '{library description}'
    website = '{github_url}

}

//Step I: Add the below line

apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'



//Step II: Add the below publish details
publish {

    def groupProjectID = 'com.an.optimize'
    def artifactProjectID = 'optimize'
    def publishVersionID = '0.1.0'

    userOrg = 'murthyanitaa'
    repoName = 'Optimize'
    groupId = groupProjectID
    artifactId = artifactProjectID
    publishVersion = publishVersionID
    desc = 'Android library for displaying data based on JSON configuration fetched from server. With this library, you can kiss goodbye to string.xml, dimen.xml, arrays.xml. Keep all your string/integer/array config in one file. The library will automatically fetch the data from the url you provide.'
    website = 'https://github.com/anitaa1990/Optimize'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha01"
}
```

Step 5: Upload to Bintray: In the terminal in Android Studio, add the below command to clean, build and upload the library to bintray:

```
gradle clean build bintrayUpload -PbintrayUser={userid_bintray} -PbintrayKey={apikey_bintray} -PdryRun=false
```

Step 6: Link to JCenter: Under your project repository in Bintray, you will see your library along with the version details you had specified. Now all you need to do is click on Add to JCenter.